# Trying to make a calculator using JavaScript but don't know how to define cases

Tags: javascript, calculator

How do i get numbers in number1 in number2 and symbols in symbol1 symbol2 and how do i set conditions like first input should not be an operator or if multiple operators then return error? Am posting a question for the first time so please excuse if it not looks clean.

Here's my js:
this are onclicks i specified:

```
function clearCalculator()
  {
   document.querySelector("#result").value = '';
  }

  function printInteger(inputFromCalculator)
  {
    document.querySelector("#result").value += inputFromCalculator;
  }

  function printSymbol(inputFromCalculator)
  {
    document.querySelector("#result").value += inputFromCalculator;
  }

  function printFinalOutput()
  {

    var expression = document.querySelector("#result").value;

    expression+="=";
    //expression 22+32+22=

    if(sanityCheck(expression)==true)
    {
      divideAndConquer(expression);


    }

  }
```

here i tried to put integers in var number1 and number2 and operators in var symbol1 and symbol2:

```
  function divideAndConquer(expression)
  {
    var number1;
    var number2;
    var symbol1;
    var symbol2;
    var miniExpressionLength;
    var partialOutput;
    for(var i=0;i<expression.length;i++)
        {
          if(isNumber(expression[i])==true && number1==null)
          { 
            number1=expression[i];
//logs number1 as single string

          }
          else
          {
            if(isNumber(expression[i])==true && number1!=null && symbol1==null)
            {
              number1 = number1 + expression[i];
            }

          }

          if(symbol1!=null && number1!=null && isNumber(expression[i])==true && number2==null)
          {
            number2 = expression[i];

          }
          else
          {
            if(symbol1!=null && number1!=null && isNumber(expression[i])==true && number2!=null && symbol2==null)
            {
              number2 = number2 + expression[i];
            }
          }


          if(isSymbol(expression[i])==true && symbol1==null)
          {
            symbol1=expression[i];
          }
          else
          {
            if(isSymbol(expression[i])==true && symbol1!=null)
            {
              symbol2=expression[i];
            }
          }if(symbol2!=null)
          {
            miniExpressionLength = i;
            //console.log("length of mini expression ="+i)
            break;
          }
        }

       partialOutput = calculate(number1,number2,symbol1);
       expression =  partialOutput+""+expression.substring(miniExpressionLength,expression.length);

      if(symbol1!=null)
      {
        divideAndConquer(expression);
      }
      else
      {
        console.log("expression ="+expression);
         return expression;
      }



  }
```

here i specified some cases:

```
function sanityCheck(expression)
    {
        //case example +2+2
        if(isNumber(expression[0])==false)
        {
            alert("invalid expression");
            return false;
        }

        for(var i=0;i<expression.length;i++)
        {

            //case example 2++2
            if(isSymbol(expression[i])==true && isSymbol(expression[i+1])==true)
            {
                alert("invalid expression");
                return false;
            }

        }
        return true;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, note that in the “if statement” if the result is already a boolean it's not necessary to use "=="

```
if(isNumber(expression[0]) == false) {
```

You can directly use the expression:

```
if(!isNumber(expression[0])) {
```

Note that the “!” (NOT gate) at the begin of the sentence ,
if the result is already false is going to pass.

I highly recommend you to user ES6 array features.
https://medium.com/poka-techblog/simplify-your-javascript-use-map-reduce-and-filter-bd02c593cc2d

sanityCheck conditions:

1. The first character have to be a Number
2. After that it have to follow the sequence Symbol-Number-Symbol-Number...

So you can use a regular expression like this:

```
^\d+([+\-\/\*]\d+)+$
```

(Test by yourself here https://regex101.com/)

Note: this only works for integers.

```
function sanityCheck(expression)
{
    const sanityExpresion = /^\d+([+\-\/\*]\d+)+$/
    return sanityExpresion.test(expression);
}
```

And you could do something like this for the divideAndConquer function:

```
function divideAndConquer(expresion) {
    const symbolSeparation = /[+\-\/\*]/
    const numberSeparation = /\d/

    const numbers = expresion.split(symbolSeparation);

    // filter where symbol !== “”
    const  symbols = expresion.split(numberSeparation).filter(s => s);

    // So I get the first number and removed from the array
    let result = numbers.shift();

    // Here I use an array function
    symbols.forEach(operator => {
        const topNumber = numbers.shift();
        result = eval(result + operator + topNumber);
    })

    return result;
}
```

It is the same if you use the eval only:

```
function divideAndConquer(expresion) {
    return eval(expresion)
}
```

But I think you want a few more action in you code to practice, so good luck. XD

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 1):

Parsing math expressions is not a simple task and is beyond the scope of an answer. There are several libraries that provide parsing.
If you want to do this for learning purpose you should have a look at:

- Reverse Polish Notation
- Abstract Syntax Trees
- The Shunting-yard algorithm

Here for example is a good blog post to get you started:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/parsing-math-expressions-with-javascript-7e8f5572276e/